# Разделитель в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, datagridview

Проблема с форматом числа в ячейки, при попытке вычитать данные столбца из datagridview и апдейтить ими таблицу в БД получаю ошибку приведения varchar к numeric. Понял что проблема в разделители числа, сейчас это "," когда стоит "." все ок. Данные в датагрид попадают из БД, в БД хранится с точкой, но в датагриде почему то получается с запятой. Что делать?

Пока сделал вот такой костыль, надеюсь кто подскажет норм решение.

```
private String separator(String someString)
{
   return someString.Replace(',', '.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Панель управления => Часы, язык и регион => Региональные стандарты => Дополнительные параметры... => Ставим нужный разделитель.

Либо можете попробовать в свойствах колонки вручную указать

```
DataGridTextBoxColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
textColumn.FormatInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

Comment: Это геморно в плане каждому пользователю обьяснять.

Comment: @Winteriscoming предложил еще вариант, проверьте

Comment: Чето не получается нет такого свойства  dgv_mainWindow.Columns["kg"].FormatInfo или вы про конструктор?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Приведите dgv_mainWindow.Columns["kg"] явно к типу DataGridTextBoxColumn и увидите это свойство.

Comment: Привел не помогает, меняю системный разделитель все становится ок, но меня ето не устраивает(

Comment: @Winteriscoming попробуй разные CultureInfo, должно сработать.

Comment: Где найти описание de-DE какая страна что использует?